# Need Help in porting Unity game to Windows phone 8.1

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I just need a little help as i am really confused about the behaviour of unity. I had ported my word puzzle game to Windows Phone 8.0 using unity 5.0.1 and it runs good on all of the windows phone devices. Now i have ported the same build to windows phone 8.1 by using unity 5.2.2 and it runs too much slow on the device. I am unable to understand why is this so and how can i optimize it. Kindly help me out in this if you can. Please share some useful links or any posts that can help me to resolve this problem. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have just managed to found the solution my self for above described issue. When you target windows phone 8.1 Just change the configuration settings from Debug to Master and make the build from VS it will run smoothly on device. Its worked for me.